# Deleting node containing address of other node

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, singly-linked-list, recursive-datastructures

I know the logic in the code given below is wrong but I have doubts about what happens when we delete p having the address of the next node.

What will the destructor do?
will it go to all the node make them null until the Next in node p don't become null

Also tell me what destructors do to memory.
I have read many articles on destructor, deallocation ,delete and free but I am still confused.
Main confusion is in deallocation and destructor.

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node(int data){
            this -> data = data;
            this -> next = NULL;
        }
    
        ~Node() {
            if(next) {
                delete next;
            }
        }
    };
```

```
void deleteAlternateNodes(Node *head) {
    //Write your code here
    Node *p =head;
    Node *q =NULL;
   if(p->next == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
        q->next = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = q->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're programming in one language, then please don't tag other irrelevant languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement of the operator delete

```
delete p;
```

all nodes that follow the node pointed to by the pointer `p` (due to the data member `next`) will be deleted.

So the function `deleteAlternateNodes` invokes undefined behavior because all nodes pointed to by the expression `q->next` that is assigned like

```
    q->next = p->next;
```

will be deleted due to this statement

```
    delete p;
```

So this statement

```
    p = q->next;
```

sets the pointer `p` to an invalid pointer.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class Node 
{
public:
    int data;
    Node * next;
    
    Node(int data)
    {
        this -> data = data;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }
    
    ~Node() 
    {
        std::cout << "The destructor is called for node with data equal to "
                  << data << '\n';

        if(next) 
        {
            delete next;
        }
    }
};

void display( const Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next )
    {
        std::cout << head->data << " -> ";
    }
    
    std::cout << "null\n";
}

int main() 
{
    Node *head = new Node( 1 );
    Node *current = head;
    current->next = new Node( 2 );
    current = current->next;
    current->next = new Node( 3 );
    
    display( head );
    
    delete head;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
The destructor is called for node with data equal to 1
The destructor is called for node with data equal to 2
The destructor is called for node with data equal to 3
```

In fact the if statement in the destructor is redundant

```
        if(next) 
        {
            delete next;
        }
```

You may just write

```
delete next;
```

without the if statement because for a null pointer the destructor will not be called. For example

```
~Node() 
{
    std::cout << "The destructor is called for node with data equal to "
              << data << '\n';

    delete next;
}
```

or

```
~Node() 
{
    delete next;
}
```

Comment: sir but the destructor u used is not default so how we will know that it will call delete for next

Comment: @Abhinav1036 There is explicitly the statement delete next; in the destructor.

Comment: sir i am talking about the case when we use default destructor will the same thing happen

Comment: @Abhinav1036 The default destructor does not contain the statement delete next;. So its behavior is different relative to the destructor in the code snippet in your question.

Comment: sir also tell me if destructor don't deallocate memory then what the use of it.

Comment: @Abhinav1036 You can reuse the memory.

Comment: sir then default destructor will not delete the node in next

Comment: @Abhinav1036 Yes, it will not because there is no statement delete next;

Comment: sir can u explain the function of destructor if it doesn't deallocate the memory then how it is destroying the object.

Comment: @Abhinav1036 Read about the placement new operator in the internet or in a book on C++.

Answer (score 0):

So the destructor is the last function that is going to be called before an object is destroyed. It is destroying (as in calling the relevant destructor for) the object instance passed to delete, and then "frees" the memory so that it can be used for other purposes.

For your code question, you deallocating the memory that was previously reserved for your node "NEXT".

Answer (score 0):

Each object in C++ begins its life with a constructor call and ends it with a destructor. For primitive types, this is no-op. For classes, you can define what both calls do.

This is orthogonal to storage of the object of which there are two:

- **Automatic** storage mean the lifetime of the object is deduced automatically based on the scope of the defined object. I.e. C++ automatically ensure that a constructor and destructors are called* for the objects. This includes:

  - **Local variables**: Ctor called when executing passed over the definition, Dtor called at the end of the scope - roughly the '}'.
  - **Local static vars**: Ctor same as previous but only for the first time, Dtor at the end of the program and only if Ctor has been called.
  - **Global vars**: Ctor called before `main`, mostly unordered, Dtor at the end of the program.
  - **Member vars**: Ctor in class's initializer list in its ctor. Dtor at the end of the class's Dtor. Even here, both functions are always called, meaning you should not and must not call dtor explicitly in class's dtor.
  - **Member static vars**: Same as global vars.
- Dynamic storage - must be explicitly requested through use `new`. C++ won't ever call `delete` for you, it is your responsibility to do so **exactly** once. `delete` calls the destructor + deallocates the memory allocated for the storage by `new`. It is **not** enough to just call the destructor explicitly. Furthermore `delete` does not modify the pointer, you must set it to `nullptr`** explicitly if the code relies on that.

*Unless program crashes.
**Do not use `NULL`.

In your example `Node::~Node` correctly destroys the `next` memory which was previously allocated by `new`. `int data` is automatically destroyed at the end of the dtor, since it is a primitive type, it's no-op. After the dtor finishes, the `Node` object is destroyed.

This is not a correct way how to destroy a linked list though, because the destructor is recursive and will easily overflow the stack for longer lists. The proper procedure is to manually iterate over the list in the dtor and `delete` the individual nodes.

Comment: can u tell me how stack will get overflow

Comment: can u also tell me how destructor recursively delete the node next to it

Comment: @Abhinav1036 If the list is long enough then because `delete next;` calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` containing `delete next;` which calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` containing `delete next;` which calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` containing `delete next;` which calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` containing `delete next;` which calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` containing `delete next;` which calls the destructor for `next` which is again `Node::~Node` contai

Comment: Ups I seem to have run out of comment's stack space.

Comment: sir what happen when destructor reaches the last node

Comment: It will stop, but it might not get there if the list has thousands of elements. There is also a tail recursion optimization which helps but it is not mandatory and might no happen with optimizations disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the destructor of `Node` will destroy all the nodes that follow it, and no, it does not make anything the null pointer (and it wouldn't help if it did since accessing an object after its destruction is undefined).

Your `deleteAlternateNodes` has undefined behaviour from accessing destroyed nodes.
A quick and dirty fix for this is to cut off the "tail" before destroying a node:

```
q->next = p->next;  // Save the tail.
p->next = nullptr;  // Cut off the tail.
delete p; // This is safe now.
```

Fixing the remaining bugs left as an exercise.
(Work it out by drawing lists using pen(cil) and paper first. This is the best method for both developing and debugging pointer-based code.)

Comment: why the destructor of Node will destroy all the nodes that follow it.

Comment: @Abhinav1036 Because `delete next` destroys the following node, and the destruction of that node will destroy *its* following node, which will destroy that node's follower, and so on.